# How does the angry_at piglin nbt work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am planning to do a manhunt with lots of things as twists (Video title would be:"Minecraft Manhunt but Buttons, Pressure plates, and Trapdoors are OP) so if you hold a blackstone button, it would spawn a piglin that takes extra knockback, targets the other player by using the Brain angry_at nbt tag, and never turns into a zombified piglin.

I have put down another question asking for how to make the piglins take extra knockback no matter what, so now I'm asking what nbt to use if I wanna spawn a piglin that targets a player called LittlePythoner(even if another nearby piglin is angry at me or something like that)?

Comment: Your question could be better received if you told us what you have tried

Comment: I don't know what to try - that's the point, and I can't try anything because I am not allowed to play at all on weekdays. Mcstacker doesn't have a brain part for piglins, and since I am on my school chromebook typing this right now, iboss blocks gamepedia and fandom, I can't go to that Mob/ED page again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command:

```
/execute as @e[type=piglin] run data modify entity @s Brain.memories.minecraft:angry_at.value set from entity LittlePythoner UUID
```

Comment: @Penguin Thanks, I didn't realize that the ticks had to be on another line for this markdown parser, I am used to using Discord markdown